# AutoMinorLocator(2) as the default matplotlib behavior

Tags: matplotlib

Is it possible to set the default minor tick locator in matplotlib such that I achieve the behavior below without the final two lines?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import AutoMinorLocator, MultipleLocator, MaxNLocator

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1, 2],[1, 2])

ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(2))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(2))
```

Comment: No it is not. Unless you edit the source code of matplotlib to achieve the desired. If you want to have an answer explaining what you need to edit in the source, please clearly state so.

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to get into editing the source code.

Comment: I do think this would be great to have, especially if it's part of `rcParams` and you're able to set as part of the theme.  Maybe I'll try to open a feature request..

Comment: Submitted a feature request: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/14233